# Faster search platform/indexing engine than Apache Solr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lucene, indexing, solr

Apache Solr came up in a discussion today, it seems it has the unique ability of being known to be the best out there, yet I still heard some people complain, especially when used in conjunction with 3rd party apps like RoR apps.

Can anyone disprove this? Better but less known options than Apache Solr for searching/indexing? Or at least something faster than Lucene.

Thank you.

Comment: If some Ruby / Solr gem is slow, how about just replacing it with another gem that isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have a look at [CLucene](http://clucene.sourceforge.net/) - Lucene ported to C++.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll investigate this option.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). There's something of a religious war between the Sphinx and Solr camps. Being a clojure developer I really appreciate the ease of integration with lucene / solr.

Both are **fast**. Unless this discussion yielded any empirical evidence that Solr is slower than some other indexing engine in a specific context, use whatever's easiest for you IMHO. Otherwise you're just prematurely optimising your project based on FUD.

Comment: Thank you, will investigate this option as well.Apparently Lucene is a must for this project, so CLucene sounds like the closest improvement unfortunately, but thank you either way.

Comment: Solr is essentially just a web service wrapped around Lucene. If you're using Solr, you're using Lucene.

Comment: +1 for "Use whatever's easiest for you IMHO. Otherwise you're just prematurely optimising your project based on FUD."

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/), a ruby gem for Apache Solr and have not faced any problems yet.

Answer (score 0):

Endeca is extremely fast and powerful, but also very expensive so of no use if you're looking for a "free" solution.